# Images in PDF are messed up when I download PDF through an API (with jquery ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

I want download an pdf from an api service using jquery. I found on this site helpful links on how to convert the data from the api (blob) to a downloadable pdf:

```
    success: function(blob){
      var link=document.createElement('a');
      var binaryData = [];
      binaryData.push(blob);
      link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData {type: "application/pdf"}));
      link.download="nameofthepdf.pdf";
      link.click();
    },
```

This code works fine except all images in the pdf are messed up,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCRaj.jpg):

[image]

[image]

[image]

(these are supposed to be graphs). It's like the conversion to pdf works well except for images in the pdf file. Anyone know how to solve this?

Update: found a solution to this problem through this helpful article:
http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/
if anyone is expiriencing similar problems.

Comment: Please **A** don't give the solution to the question in the question text but instead in an answer, and **B** don't merely link to an outside page but write the pivotal information here as external links might be taken down one way or another rendering your link useless.